# Qt QWidget/QDialog window is moved some time after creation on Linux

Tags: c++, qt

This is a simple testcase of a window saving its position when it's closed:

- a dialog is created, and it is moved via `QWidget::move` to the last saved position
- in dialog's `closeEvent`, `QWidget::pos` is saved

Repeatedly creating/destroying should place the windows in the same position it was when it was closed.

Works fine on Windows and macOS.

On Linux, the window is shifted by (0, -37) some time after creation. Repeatedly creating/destroying the window causes the window to gradually shift upwards.

From the logged messages on macOS and Windows we see:

```
dialog pos after creation QPoint(200,200)
dialog pos (button clicked)  QPoint(200,200)
dialog pos before close QPoint(200,200)
dialog pos after creation QPoint(200,200)
dialog pos (button clicked)  QPoint(200,200)
dialog pos before close QPoint(200,200)
```

while on Linux (Ubuntu 20) we see:

```
dialog pos after creation QPoint(200,200)
dialog pos (button clicked)  QPoint(200,163)
dialog pos before close QPoint(200,163)
dialog pos after creation QPoint(200,163)
dialog pos (button clicked)  QPoint(200,126)
dialog pos before close QPoint(200,126)
dialog pos after creation QPoint(200,126)
dialog pos (button clicked)  QPoint(200,89)
dialog pos before close QPoint(200,89)
dialog pos after creation QPoint(200,89)
dialog pos (button clicked)  QPoint(200,52)
dialog pos before close QPoint(200,52)
dialog pos after creation QPoint(200,52)
dialog pos before close QPoint(200,27)
```

I thought as a workaround I would use `geometry()` / `setGeometry()` instead of `pos()` / `move()`, but then other problems arise.

Is this a bug? Is there a better solution to this?

Another solution I considered, is saving the dialog position some time later, but upon which event? I tried `showEvent`, but in that case reported position is (0, 0).

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QPoint>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    QPushButton *btn;

    friend class QDialog2;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QCloseEvent>
#include <QPoint>
#include <QDialog>
#include <QDebug>

QPoint savedPos;
class QDialog2 *theDialog;

class QDialog2 : public QDialog
{
    MainWindow *mainWindow;

public:
    QDialog2(MainWindow *w, QWidget *parent = 0)
        : QDialog(parent), mainWindow(w)
    {
    }

    virtual void closeEvent(QCloseEvent * event)
    {
        qDebug() << "dialog pos before close" << this->pos();
        savedPos = this->pos();
        this->deleteLater();
        theDialog = nullptr;
    }
};

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    theDialog = nullptr;

    btn = new QPushButton(this);
    btn->setText("Create");

    connect(btn, &QPushButton::clicked, [=] {
        if(theDialog) {
            qDebug() << "dialog pos (button clicked) " << theDialog->pos();
            theDialog->close();
            btn->setText("Create");
            return;
        }

        theDialog = new QDialog2(this, this);
        Qt::WindowFlags flags = Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::WindowTitleHint | Qt::WindowSystemMenuHint;
#if __APPLE__
        flags |= Qt::Tool;
#else
        flags |= Qt::Dialog;
#endif
        flags |= Qt::MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint;
        flags |= Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint;
        theDialog->setWindowFlags(flags);
        theDialog->setModal(false);
        theDialog->setEnabled(true);
        theDialog->show();
        if(savedPos.isNull()) theDialog->move(QPoint(200, 200));
        else theDialog->move(savedPos);
        theDialog->resize(250, 250);
        btn->setText("Destroy");
        qDebug() << "dialog pos after creation" << theDialog->pos();
    });
    setCentralWidget(btn);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming the Linux display is X11 based?  If so, I suspect you're probably at the mercy of whichever window manager you're using.  It can decide to honour size/placement requests but is also free to ignore them.  The vertical offset of 37 pixels sounds suspiciously like the height of the window manager's title bar.  If so I'd guess a request to place your window at (x, y) is actually placing the decorated parent window created by the manager at (x, y) -- if that makes sense?

Comment: Well explained here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/application-windows.html#x11-peculiarities

Comment: That peculiarity of X11 is clear. What's then an event that when it fires, I can be sure that the window is in its final position, i.e. such window moving has already happened?